# Qual a finalidade da opção avoid_negative_ts na transcodificação do ffmpeg?

Tags: vídeo, streaming

Gostaria de saber detalhes sobre essa funcionalidade, pois não existem muitas informações a respeito. Pelo pouco que entendi, me parece que ativando essa opção, terei uma melhoria quando ocorrer uma perda de *frame*, mas não estou certo a respeito disso.

O que cada uma de seus comandos ira fazer quando for chamado?

Os comandos são:

```
avoid_negative_ts 1
avoid_negative_ts 0
avoid_negative_ts auto
avoid_negative_ts disabled
avoid_negative_ts make_zero
avoid_negative_ts make_non_negative
avoid_negative_ts skip_initial_bytes
```